# A riddle on bhagavad gita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, sanskrit

Someone asked me to help them find a philosophical term from gita which is used in relation with another philosophical term and both of them together make an important term. ( hint is both start from the same vyanjana, is strilinga and is not sruti, means the term is not "sruti")

Do help us if you yourself know or know anyone from your sampradaya who has studied the bhagavad gita .